# PHP - for loop should execute only one time for prefix

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need a for loop which executes only one time so that I can add prefix (1 to 10 numbers) to a text

```
foreach($_POST['Checked'] as $check){

    if($check== ""){                                     
        $check= " ";                                             
    } else {                                                                 
        $check= " ".$check;                                      
    }

    $html .= '<div style="font-family:Arial;padding: 4px;"> - '.$check.'</div>';
}
```

The outut of my code

- Test
- Demo
- Testing
- Verification
- Validation

What I need:

1. Test
2. Demo
3. Testing
4. Verification
5. Validation

I wrote a for loop but it displays as

1. Test
2. Demo
3. Testing
4. Verification
5. Validation
6. Test
7. Demo
8. Testing
9. Verification
10. Validation

Which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Just use an ordered list (`<ol>`) instead of `<div>`s

Comment: Why javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andreas said, you should be using an `<ol>` instead of just divs.

First, put `<ol>` before the `for()` loop, then close it (`</ol>`) after the loop. Then instead of the `<div>` inside your for loop, make it an `<li>` tag.

However, if what you wanted to do was to print the number instead of having the HTML render a number for you, you could do something like:

```
foreach($_POST['Checked'] as $n=>$checked)
```

This creates a variable `$n` which is the array key for the value `$checked`. So if the key of `Test` is `0`, echoing `$n . '. ' . $checked` will get you `0. Test`. The next would be `1. Demo`, etc etc

You should use `<ol>` in this use case, but I thought I'd throw in the array key thing since it's an alternate solution that could prove useful elsewhere if you don't know it already.